# Is it wrong to use shorthand if/else statements in this way

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactjs and I'm trying to improve the quality of my code. In the example below, I have a pure function that is used by another component to return a list of users. Within my code, I use shorthand if/else statements. Is this the right way to write something like this, or is there a cleaner way for readability and error minimization. Thanks for any insights.

```
function CandidateList(props) {
  return (
    <Row className="candidate-white-background">
      <Col xs={3} sm={2}>
        {
          props.candidate.profileAvatarURL
          ? <Image className="img-responsive" src={props.candidate.profileAvatarURL} rounded />
          : <Alert bsStyle="danger" className="text-center nothing-in-section-alert-box">
              No Profile Image
            </Alert>
        }
      </Col>
      <Col xs={9} sm={10}>
        { props.candidate.name ? <Link to={`/admin/candidate_profile/${props.candidate.userId}`}> <h3 className="candidate-profile-name">{(props.candidate.name.first + ' ' + props.candidate.name.last)}</h3></Link> : 'No name' }

        { props.candidate.professionalOverview ? <h4>{(props.candidate.professionalOverview.currentCompany + ' ' + props.candidate.professionalOverview.currentTitle)}</h4> : 'Mobile missing' }
        { props.candidate.summary ? <p>{props.candidate.summary.substring(0, 300)}</p> : 'No summary' }
        { props.candidate.contact ? <p><FontAwesome className="fa-fw" name="mobile"/>{props.candidate.contact.mobile}</p> : <p><FontAwesome className="fa-fw" name="mobile" />N/A</p> }
        { props.candidate.address ? <p><FontAwesome className="fa-fw" name="map-marker"/>{props.candidate.address.fullAddress}</p> : <p><FontAwesome className="fa-fw" name="map-marker" />N/A</p> }
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the ternarys? I'd say in a case like that, they should be avoided. Those lines are already very noisy. This is a pretty subjective question though.

Comment: I think its your only option in `jsx`

Comment: Yes. I was talking about the ternarys. You mentioned it's noisy. How could you do it to make it less noisy?

Comment: @bp123 By "noisy", I meant that that line contains of ton of punctuation, so it takes a sec to see the ternary operator symbols among the other symbols. I'd split it over a couple lines, or abstract them away into a function if possible.

Comment: You could use self calling functions when there is such complex ternary usage. They make code more readable and cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorthand is called a "ternary expression" and it's completely acceptable. As far as "the right way" 'we' know that there really is no "right way" when programming. You should use patterns that make your code more readable and easy to understand. I personally think that ternary expressions are very straight forward and make the code easy to reason about.

I personally like to put my ternaries like so

```
{ this.state.someProp 
 ? <AThing/> 
 : <SomeOtherThing/> 
}
```

That way i can easily see at a glance what's what. This is all up to your own personal style though.